# Select2 Ajax won't show the results

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm having issues witht the select2

```
$('#charity_user_id').select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "/get-users",
      dataType: 'get',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
         return {
             results: data
         };
     },
      cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 4,
  });
```

My ajax call result is something like this:

```
[{id: 24941, text: "mail@mail.com"}]
```

Why is select2 not showing the results? It just says "The results could not be loaded"

Comment: `dataType` can't be `get`. That should be json, jsonp, etc

Comment: Oh dear, I went crazy over this, I tried a copy and paste from another answer and it screw all! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem man, it happens.